Handle large amount of user default table types in stored procedure
We have some dynamic stored procedures that have very similar logic and they use bunch of user defined table type as input parameters. The common approach how we handle these types is:
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure
    @importantParam1 dbo.SomeType READONLY,
    ....
BEGIN
  
    DECLARE @nrOfImportantParam1 INT = 0;
    DECLARE @singleImportantParam1 NVARCHAR(35);
    SELECT @nrOfImportantParam1 = COUNT(*) FROM @importantParam1;
    IF (@nrOfImportantParam1 = 1)
        SELECT @singleImportantParam1 = [value] FROM @importantParam1;

    ....

    SET @joinQuery = 
    ...
    + CASE WHEN @nrOfImportantParam1 > 1 THEN 'INNER JOIN @importantParam1 t ON t.[value] = tbl.SomeKey' ELSE '' END
    ...

    SET @filterQuery = 
    ...
    + CASE WHEN @nrOfImportantParam1 = 2 THEN 'AND tbl.SomeKey = @singleImportantParam1' ELSE '' END
    
END

Every time we add new user defined table type we need to add new parameter and new logic to handle it. I would like to have some generic approach to handle this. Do you have any suggestions how to reduce such code duplication?
Most probably it should be some kind of stored procedure that will return 2 output params: 1 for join query snippet and another one for filter query snippet. However adding new user defined table type would require to add new case in this stored procedure + there could be problems with aliases and join keys as they might differ little bit in every SP.
UPDATE:
The normal use case of procedure like that is to return filtered data from ~5 big tables. There are a lot of filters that could be passed to this SP and the most of them are optional. Some filters are using table value params to pass more than 1 value for single filter, for example: list of statuses, list of users and so on. Normally they have 1-5 values and the dynamic SQL is used mostly to eliminate kitchen sink problem which appears in constructions like: WHERE (some_col = @some_param OR @some_param IS NULL). With set of ~50 params this problem can be just huge.

You can probably keep some repository of parameters and joins for every table type and fields, but i don't know, what are you needed so many dynamic procedures for? And how similar are those parameters? If you have a procedure per some table, perhaps it's better to write some template procedure which generates some boilerplate code (that's what we did with over 4k of procs)

The fact you need dynamic queries is likely the real problem here, if I am honest. This is then, presumably, causing you to go down a "dynamic table type parameter" route, and causing you to then be asking this question about needing a generic, but dynamic, table type; those don't exist.

@siggemannen what do you mean by saying repository of parameters? There are not just a lot of similar stored procedures, however there are around 5 of them with similar logic and similar parameters sets. They are not per table basis, they are more like search/get procedures that are returning results based on the set of 50+ filters/params.

And why are there multiple tables if they're so similar you can use the same 50 columns everywhere? And why are there multiple table types used? This sounds like a design problem. Adding more SQL generation may get you from 20 to 50 types but you'll keep hitting a wall every time.

Never mind that using a stored procedure that generates and returns dynamic SQL to a client is the worst possible option. T-SQL is very bad at text manipulation. A client-side query builder or an ORM would do a better job, especially if this is a multi-tenancy scenario as I suspect. Besides, tables and types don't change from one query to the next either, so you could generate views and functions based on templates just once, and call a different one each time

I mean like a table of: tabletypecolumnName, join_value, column_filter where you can store what the table type columns mean when it comes to dynamic sql, and which you can fetch when doing your procedures. Not sure it's worth the effort though

@PanagiotisKanavos multiple table types are used to pass more than 1 value to it. For examples list_of_statuses, list_of_users and so on. I'm not sure that separate views and/or functions would help, as the main joins are to the table types. Physical tables are ~5, but they can be filtered by many columns.

Weirder and weirder. Table types aren't needed for bulk imports if eg you use ADO.NET's SqlBulkCopy. They're needed if you try to emulate batch, not bulk, imports. Or if you try to use a single stored procedure to perform transformations in an ETL job instead of using an ETL tool like SSIS. What you described sound like lookup data that could be bulk inserted into staging tables and used in those JOINs

Besides, table variables don't have statistics even with indexes. Each TVP is assumed to have just 1 row. The performance of the generated query will be bad. The data isn't held in memory either, it's stored in TempDB. If you use staging tables on the other hand you can have proper indexes and statistics and storage you can control

This is not about ETL or any kind of OLAP, this is being used in OLTP use case and should be returned quickly enough. TVP would normally have just few records (1-5), so I assume that stats are not very needed in such case. Staging tables might not be an option there as normally they would give good benefit when we need to return a lot of data. In this particular case it is more expected to have ~3-10 filters, each of them could have ~1-5 values. I understand all of your concerns, however it is something that I got implemented already and not everything could be easily re-designed.

Updated the question little bit

This just screams of being a very challenging architecture. And the likelihood this is vulnerable to sql injection can't be ignored.

Dynamic SQL in stored procedures, it's rarely a good idea. Not saying it's never done, but it should in most cases be avoided. From what I see you are doing in the fragment, you're trying to make some sort of catch-all query, and that's also typically not a good idea.

Btw, why don't you reuse the same TVP?

Based on the OP's comment "multiple table types are used to pass more than 1 value to it. For examples list_of_statuses, list_of_users and so on.", it looks like they have a generic search SP, and are using User Defined Table Types to pass a list to the SP (e.g., a list of statuses selected in the UI). @DmitrijKultasev is that accurate? If so, there's a much easier way to do this, without the need for dynamic SQL at all, especially since you said you only have 5 underlying tables.

@SeanLange SQL injections should not be a problem as sys.sp_executesql + params is used to execute dynamic SQL.
@siggemannen we are re-using the same TVP, however the problem is that there are a lot of params being passed to procedure with the same TVP.

@HardCode I understand that there could be another way of doing so, however this is what I've got to be working with, not something I designed and it is not so easy to re-design everything from scratch. There are only 5 tables, but number of params is big and most of them are optional and having smf like (param = column or param is null) for all of these params is not performing well.

"Every time we add new user defined table type we need to add new parameter and new logic to handle it. I would like to have some generic approach to handle this. Do you have any suggestions how to reduce such code duplication?" You could probably add insult to injury by using DDL triggers to dynamically build your stored procedure, making it that much harder to maintain and debug - but TBH, I would probably advise to reconsider this entire approach in favor of a simpler one.
